# Google Maps API V3 - Showing progress along a route

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I want to show a custom route on a route along with the current progress. I've overlayed the a Polyline to show the route and I am able to find the LatLng of the current postion and place a marker. What I want to do now is to highlight the traveled part of the Polyline using a different colour. I'm pretty sure it's not possible to have multiple colours for one Polyline so I plan to overlay a second Polyline over the first the first to give this effect. Here's my question:

Knowing the LatLng of the current position and armed with the array of LatLng points used to create the orginal Polyline how best can I create the second 'Progess' route?

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1):

With a few assumptions:

- Your path is quite dense (if not, you could interpolate intermediate points)
- Your route doesn't overlap with itself (wouldn't work with a repeating circular path, say)

..one crude way would be as follows:

Using Python'y pseudo-code, say you have a route like this:

```
points = [LatLng(1, 1), LatLng(2, 2), LatLng(3, 3), LatLng(4, 4)]
```

You draw this as a PolyLine as usual.

Then, given your current position, you would find the nearest point on the route:

```
cur_pos = LatLng(3.1, 3.0123)

nearest_latlng = closest_point(points, to = cur_pos)
```

Then `nearest_latlng` would contain `LatLng(3, 3)`

Find `nearest_latlng` in the list, then simply draw a second polyline up to this point. In other words, you truncate the `points` list at the current LatLng:

```
progress_points = [LatLng(1, 1), LatLng(2, 2), LatLng(3, 3)]
```

..then draw that on the map

As mentioned, this will break if the path loops back on itself (`closest_point` would only ever find the first or last point)

If you know how far has been travelled, there is an [epoly](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/epoly.htm) extension which gives a few methods that could be used, mainly:

```
.GetIndexAtDistance(metres)
Returns the vertex number at or after the specified distance along the path.
```

That index could be used instead of the `closest_point` calculated one above

Answer (score 1):

Typescript example:

```
getRouteProgressPoints(directionResult: google.maps.DirectionsResult | undefined, targetDistance: number) {
  if (!directionResult || targetDistance <= 0) return [];

  const route = directionResult.routes[0];
  const leg: google.maps.DirectionsLeg = route.legs[0];
  const routePoints: google.maps.LatLng[] = [];

  // collect all points
  leg.steps.forEach((step) => {
    step.path.forEach((stepPath) => {
      routePoints.push(stepPath);
    });
  });

  let dist = 0;
  let olddist = 0;
  const points = [];

  // go throw all points until target
  for (let i = 0; i < routePoints.length && dist < targetDistance; i++) {
    const currentPoint = routePoints[i];

    // add first point
    if (!i) {
      points.push(currentPoint);
      continue;
    }

    const prevPoint = routePoints[i - 1];
    olddist = dist;
    // add distance between points
    dist += google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(prevPoint, currentPoint);

    if (dist > targetDistance) {
      const m = (targetDistance - olddist) / (dist - olddist);
      const targetPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(
        prevPoint.lat() + (currentPoint.lat() - prevPoint.lat()) * m,
        prevPoint.lng() + (currentPoint.lng() - prevPoint.lng()) * m,
      );
      points.push(targetPoint);
    } else {
      points.push(currentPoint);
    }
  }
  return points;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is going to be really difficult unless you already have a way of determining that the vehicle has passed certain points already.  If you are aware that it has passed certain points you just create the second polyline with the passed points and the current marker as the end of the polyline.  You will probably want to change the width of the polyline in order to make it viewable when it is overlaying the initial route.

All of that being said if you don't know if the points have been passed I am not sure what you can do other than write some sort of code that determines if your current position is past a certain set of points, but I don't know how you do that if a route zigzags all over the place possibly.....  Now if your points go from straight west to straight east etc, than coding something will be easy, but I doubt that is the case.

Hope this helps somewhat....